# How to implement "Send Feedback" feature in Android?

Tags: android

[image]I would like this to behave just like the "Send Feedback" behaves when you click on the Menu item in the Google+ Android app.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the relevant code, the logcat errors, and a brief description of why it might not work.

Comment: @Sam I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure what to do. But I have attached a screen shot of what I was talking about in the original post. After clicking on the "Send Feedback" menu item the user is presented with the screenshot above. This is similar to how Error Reports are sent to the original developer.

Comment: Ok, the basic layout is simple a TextView, an EditView, and a couple Buttons. The next question is how / where do you want to send / store the feedback? Do you want them as emails, in a database, something else? Do you have a server set up to receive the feedback?

Comment: This looks to be more of an OS type thing and not a custom view. The reason I say that is because this is the same screen a user is presented with when he/she reports an issue to a developer (i.e. ANR or Force Close). I could be wrong though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418108/google-plus-send-feedback-tool

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812432/how-to-use-send-feeback-feedbackactivity-in-android

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how this app behaves with the "Send Feedback". Could you explain it to me, so I do not have to download the app?

As I do not know what it looks like, I am just going to take a guess and supply you with one way of letting the user send feedback:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater hardwaremenu = getMenuInflater();
    hardwaremenu.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.sendEmail:
        Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Email.setType("text/email");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "admin@hotmail.com" });
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dear ...," + "");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Send Feedback:"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Either incorporate this into your existing menu or simply add this onto the bottom of the Activity that you would like to display the menu.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's a way to send an email with some feedback, for sure, but I hope there's a way to use the issue developer feedback feature from Android itself to gather feedback into the developer console, exactly like the G+ app does.

Comment: Many Google apps use The question feedback style, usually with a screenshot. It would be great if they provided a way to do that too, as @galex Said, sending it to The developer console (at least it looks a lot like when you hit The "report" button in an n APP error)

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to catch any unhandled Exceptions and submit them as Bug Reports to your own Site or a Google Docs Spreadsheet youu should have a look at ACRA (https://github.com/ACRA/acra/). It has an option to ask the user for written feedback before sending the Bugreport to you.

Comment: That's not it either. I was there's a service to start with intent BUG_REPORT by decompiling the g+ app. This needs more investigation.

Comment: @galex Have you found the proper intent/extras to support that way of reporting bugs? I would love to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: It's my own project

I'm currently working on this: http://www.android-feedback.com which ,I think, is what you are looking for. If you want to participate in the beta just leave your e-mail addr on the form.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Its good, but a privacy policy would be nice. And please update your site's feedback too. I really don't want to send an email. A simple contact page with `area` could be better. :)

Comment: can u please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001170/show-dialog-of-android-feedback-com-library ?

Comment: You should put some code in The answer.

Comment: The link is dead