# Application-Integrated "Send Feedback"

Tags: android, google-plus, user-feedback

I'm looking for an .jar or library project that will allow users of my application to easily send feedback **from inside the application** about their experience.

As asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320685/how-to-implement-send-feedback-feature-in-android), I am looking for something similar to the crash reporting tool used in Google Plus, that allows the user to get in contact with me, besides leaving bad reviews.

Some not-quite there solutions that came up in answers to other questions:

1. [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) : Application Crash Report for Android (functions as a crash reporting tool)
2. [Hockey Kit](http://hockeykit.net/index.html): Helps distribute betas, nothing related to send feedback to developer.

Does a library like this exist? Is there an easy way to gather user feedback from within the application?

Comment: link to hockey kit is broken (it is pointing to acra)

Answer (score 6):

For a full-featured user support service, you can have a look to Capptain: http://www.capptain.com/

But with ACRA you can also trigger a report programmatically. You could call the method handleException(new UserRequestedException()) when the user selects an option in your preferences screen, for example.

You would then filter your ACRA reports spreadsheet for all stacktraces containing UserRequestedException.

UserRequestedException would be a custom Exception that you would implement.

The NOTIFICATION mode can be configured to display a form containing an e-mail field and comments field. The e-mail given by the user the first time is saved in the apps preferences.

Comment: For capptain, I really only see it mentioned once by techcrunch, which talks about how young the company is, and like you said, it seems more like a full solution rather than a simple feedback system.

This also seems like its hacking a current to do something similar, but doesn't seem very clean or portable. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to answer your question, but you might want check out this: http://www.android-feedback.com/ . Its an in app feedback / support system. Its not live yet, but the beta stage is going to start in a few weeks. (and beta testers get bumped to the premium/paid plan once live)

**Edit**: Disclaimer: its my project

Comment: can u please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001170/show-dialog-of-android-feedback-com-library ?

Comment: I can not recommend this platform since it has not been updated in a while and uses old APIs.

Comment: @FelixD. yeah, I want to create a github repo with it... I just need to find the time

Comment: Oh, that's nice to hear. Although you might also compare it to other services and decide whether it can compete. I am not saying I can't, but it certainly would need a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use a tool like [instabug](https://instabug.com/) it provides you a way for collecting bug reports and feedbacks about user experience and also you can talk back to them

Answer (score 0):

As of this date (27th April 2018), HockeyApp can handle this issue. It enables users to send In-app Feedback to developers, which then developers can access through a Dashboard.

Check out: [www.hockeyapp.net](http://www.hockeyapp.net)

The problem I've had with implementing HockeyApp, is that, the feedback form requires the user to add unnecessary details like name, email, etc. I can't seem to find a way to add these detail programmatically.