# Show dialog of "android-feedback.com" library

Tags: android, user-feedback

I am following the tutorial given here http://www.android-feedback.com/library for sending feedback. But I am unable to show dialog in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //menu.add("Email");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:

            // do whatever
            FeedbackSettings feedbackSettings = new FeedbackSettings();

            //SUBMIT-CANCEL BUTTONS
            feedbackSettings.setCancelButtonText("No");
            feedbackSettings.setSendButtonText("Send");

            //DIALOG TEXT
            feedbackSettings.setText("Hey, would you like to give us some feedback so that we can improve your experience?");
            feedbackSettings.setYourComments("Type your question here...");
            feedbackSettings.setTitle("Feedback Dialog Title");

            //TOAST MESSAGE
            feedbackSettings.setToast("Thank you so much!");
            feedbackSettings.setToastDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  // Default
            feedbackSettings.setToastDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            //RADIO BUTTONS
            feedbackSettings.setRadioButtons(false); // Disables radio buttons
            feedbackSettings.setBugLabel("Bug");
            feedbackSettings.setIdeaLabel("Idea");
            feedbackSettings.setQuestionLabel("Question");

            //RADIO BUTTONS ORIENTATION AND GRAVITY
            feedbackSettings.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); // Default
            feedbackSettings.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            feedbackSettings.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // Default
            feedbackSettings.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            feedbackSettings.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            //SET DIALOG MODAL
            feedbackSettings.setModal(true); //Default is false

            //DEVELOPER REPLIES
            feedbackSettings.setReplyTitle("Message from the Developer");
            feedbackSettings.setReplyCloseButtonText("Close");
            feedbackSettings.setReplyRateButtonText("RATE!");

            //DEVELOPER CUSTOM MESSAGE (NOT SEEN BY THE END USER)
            feedbackSettings.setDeveloperMessage("This is a custom message that will only be seen by the developer!");

            feedBack = new FeedbackDialog(this, "AF-548BD4EFE07D-89", feedbackSettings);

            feedBack.show();  

        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am unable to show the dialog on click of item !

Please help me to identify my mistake !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You're not adding a menu in onCreateOptionsMenu. When you define a menu, use R.id.your_menu_item_id not 0.