# Does Android send crash/freeze reports to Google's Play Store even if the app was not downloaded using the Play app?

Tags: android, google-play

Example: When sending a beta version to beta testers, I'll still want all of their crash/freeze reports to be sent to 'Google Play' (Former 'Android market').

Note: Such a beta version can be published by email (for example) and not downloaded using 'Google Play'. It would be installed manually by allowing 'Unknown sources'.

Comment: I use Flurry in all my apps now.  It will do a stack trace on crash and you can check relevant information on the users devices.

Comment: I don't think it does, this is somewhat related to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559267/how-to-reuse-launch-intent-action-bug-report-and-use-it-as-a-normal-feedback-f Let me know if you find something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Google Play doesn't literally "track" crashes. What it actually does is give the user the option to send a report when the app needs to Force Close (e.g. there's an unhandled exception).

So, **no**. That option is not available unless the app was downloaded from Google Play.

Comment: Why do you think the option is not available unless the app was downloaded from Google Play?

Comment: @kilaka I know it's not available from my own testing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is loaded from the market it wouldn't likely track it.  Use Flurry, it's simple to add and works on apps emailed, downloaded, or whatever.

Comment: What do you mean by likely? Yes or no? And why?

Comment: I was trying to say no in a nice way, but no it wouldn't keep up with it unless it was loaded from the market.  It wouldn't even know it existed.  Like I said, what you are trying to achieve can easily be done in Flurry or Bugsense.