# Leaving feedback in the market for application does not work

Tags: android, google-play, feedback

I had made one application and it was OK, but didn't provide the feedback option to the users. Now I made another app and trying to put feedback option - leaving feedback for the app thing from the mobile itself.

I checked the following link for the help and used the same code to put in my app:
 [How to launch the Google Play intent in 'Give Feedback' mode on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893350/how-to-launch-the-market-intent-in-give-feedback-mode-on-android)

```
String pkgnm = getPackageName();
Intent mktfdbk = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + pkgnm));
mktfdbk.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(mktfdbk);
```

My app is using an `AlertDialog` where user would click on "YES" to possibly leave the feedback on market.
Obviously at the moment my app is not in the market it wont show up anything even if using above code... but seeing the code and just for testing purpose I changed the package name to my previous app which I created and is still in the market.

But when executing the above code, it tries to connect to internet and then says "The requested item could not be found". Internet access is there, I have also used uses-permission for internet (not even sure if that was needed but I put it anyways). What am I doing wrong?